# amCharts add string series from data as tooltip to XY graph

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Wondering how I can add a string that's apart of my JSON data to the timestamp X axis tooltip.

To explain the scenario, I want to see the current on-air item paired with the timestamp in my X axis tooltip to let me know when the item was on air.

[The Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlh6A.png)

[The Desired State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtOQ7.png)

Basically I'd like the X axis tooltip with the timestamp to say "12/18 13:45:16 | J370546 JAI Sterling Silver & 14K.....etc"

This is what each data object looks like in my JSON, I'd be including the .item property value in the tooltip

```
{
        "tstamp": "2020-12-18T18:51:16.917Z",
        "que": 20,
        "vol": 382,
        "item": "J366679 JAI Sterling Silver Choice of Symbols of Love Necklace"
},
```

Comment: On x axes add the following function  (name_of_x _axes).adapter.add("getTooltipText", (text, target) => {
 return ">>> " + text + " <<<";
}); for more info see https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/

Comment: Tried that but didn't quite work out, I ended up creating another X-Axis with the current item, works better for UX anyways : ) your advice did get me here so thank you